# @ResponseBody, don't respect the constructors of an object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a @restController type controller, when I access a resource for a request I get a json as a response, the problem is that all attributes appear to me and it does not respect the constructors I have generated.

However, all the attributes of the class always appear to me:

```
{
  "code":0,
  "message":"ERROR",
  "details":null
}
```

And I would like the answer to be like this:

```
{
  "code":0,
  "message":"ERROR"
}
```

I appreciate your help

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class WsController implements WsInterface{

 @Override
 @PostMapping("/add")
    public Response add(@RequestBody Person person) {
        Response r= =null;
        if(person.getName().equals("A")){
          r= new Response(1,"OK","Details of person");
        }else{
          r= new Response (0,"ERROR");
        }
        return r;
    }
}

public class Response{

    private int code;
    private String message;
    private String details;

    public Response() {
    }

    public Response(int code, String message, String details) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public Response(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
```

Comment: What's the resolution on this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same object in both cases with null details and without. You can try to configure json serialization accordingly.Spring by default use Jackson and you can configure object mapper directly or use annotation [@JsonInclude(Include.NOT_NULL)](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_NULL) on model class to include only `not null` values.